# email is not sent using simpleMailMessage

Tags: java, spring-boot, email, spring-restcontroller

I am trying to send an email using spring boot to do so I created an account on  [mailtrap.io](https://mailtrap.io/) and I added the necessary configuration like below

```
 spring.mail.host=smtp.mailtrap.io
spring.mail.port=2525
spring.mail.username=0cfcf8adb32fea
spring.mail.password=20d3c0f7a44694
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
```

then i created a configuration java file like this :

```
package com.example.databasedemo;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Emailcfg {
    @Value("${spring.mail.host}")
    private String host;

    @Value("${spring.mail.port}")
    private int port;

    @Value("${spring.mail.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${spring.mail.password}")
    private String password;

    public String getHost() {
        return host;
    }

    public void setHost(String host) {
        this.host = host;
    }

    public int getPort() {
        return port;
    }

    public void setPort(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

and a Rest controller:

```
    package com.example.databasedemo;

import org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;


import javax.validation.ValidationException;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/Mail")
public class mailController {

    private Emailcfg emailCfg;
    public  mailController(Emailcfg emailCfg){
        this.emailCfg = emailCfg;
    }


    @GetMapping
    public void senddmail(){

        // Create a mail sender
        JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        mailSender.setHost(this.emailCfg.getHost());
        mailSender.setPort(this.emailCfg.getPort());
        mailSender.setUsername(this.emailCfg.getUsername());
        mailSender.setPassword(this.emailCfg.getPassword());
        // Create an email instance
        SimpleMailMessage mailMessage = new SimpleMailMessage();
       mailMessage.setFrom("elahidri.eh@gmail.com");
        mailMessage.setTo("elahidri.eh@gmail.com");
        mailMessage.setSubject("mail");
        mailMessage.setText("this is a mail test ");

        // Send mail
        mailSender.send(mailMessage);

    }

}
```

when I tried to execute it I got no error but I did not receive the email even throw I found the email in the mailtrap.io box 
 **UPDATE** 
this is the message I got when I debug it :

```
DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.6.1
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle]}
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]}
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.mailtrap.io", port 2525, isSSL false
220 mailtrap.io ESMTP ready
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "smtp.mailtrap.io", port: 2525
EHLO elahidri
250-mailtrap.io
250-SIZE 5242880
250-PIPELINING
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250-DSN
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN CRAM-MD5
250 STARTTLS
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "5242880"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "DSN", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "PLAIN LOGIN CRAM-MD5"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
STARTTLS
220 2.0.0 Start TLS
EHLO elahidri
250-mailtrap.io
250-SIZE 5242880
250-PIPELINING
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250-DSN
250 AUTH PLAIN LOGIN CRAM-MD5
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "5242880"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "DSN", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "PLAIN LOGIN CRAM-MD5"
DEBUG SMTP: protocolConnect login, host=smtp.mailtrap.io, user=0cfcf8adb32fea, password=<non-null>
DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate using mechanisms: LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 NTLM XOAUTH2 
DEBUG SMTP: Using mechanism LOGIN
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN succeeded
QUIT
221 2.0.0 Bye
```

Answer (score 1):

First make sure your account's 2-Step Verification is disable. Then follow the steps:

1. Go to your google account security settings(Manage your Google
   Account)
2. Click Security menu on the left side
3. Scroll down and find Less secure app access.
4. ON the allow less secure apps toggle button.

Or click the link:
https://myaccount.google.com/u/3/lesssecureapps?pageId=none

Then use this setting for email in your project application.properties or java configuration file(As like your's).

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=your_email_account
spring.mail.password=password
spring.mail.properties.mail.transport.protocol=smtp
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=false
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.encoding=UTF-8
spring.mail.properties.mail.from.email=your_email_account
```

That's it. Check whether your email is send or not.

**NOTE: This setting is not working for accounts with 2-Step Verification is enable.**

Answer (score 0):

Please debug by adding the following config in your property file.

spring.mail.debug=true

Comment: spring.mail.debug=true was unnowen so i added spring.mail.properties.mail.debug=true but i got nothing

Comment: @ElaHidri Update the debug console output.

Comment: I am sorry but I do not know how

Comment: If you enabled the debug mail property, log messages will be printed in console.

Comment: you can see in the UPDATE part the message generated from debugging

Comment: There is no error. Did you checked your spam/junk folder?